# - (void)add<NAME>Object: function

Tags: iphone, ios, properties

If you define a property for a mutable array...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;
```

Then you start to write the function... `- (void)addObje...` then auto complete will finish then name and give you...

```
- (void)addObjectsObject:(<#object-type#> *)object
{
}
```

My question is, how should I be using this function?

Do I have to call

```
[self addObjectsObject:someObject];
```

or can I just do

```
[self.objects addObject:someObject];
```

i.e. will the NSMutableArray property know that I've overridden the add object function and use my defined function to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[self addObjectsObject:someObject];`.

`[self.objects addObject:someObject];` will invoke the NSMutableArray's method directly on the property.

EDIT:

Some more information:

```
[self addObjectsObject: someObject];//calls the method - (void)addObjectsObject:
[self.objects addObject: someObject];//calls the property directly
```

If you want to override your method, you need to sub-class or you can make a category, but do not use same method name to override an existing category.